# Enabling embedded controls in a FlowDocument

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-3.5

I have a FlowDocument in a standard WPF application window where I have some text, and in this text some hyperlinks and buttons.

The problem is, if I put this FlowDocument inside anything **except** a [FlowDocumentPageViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentpageviewer.aspx) the hyperlinks and buttons are disabled ("grayed out").

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
  <FlowDocument>
      <Paragraph>
        Hello, World!
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="some-uri">click me</Hyperlink>
        <Button Click="myButton_Click" Content="Click me too!" />
      </Paragraph>
  </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

The above will work and the link will be clickable. However, I don't want the full pageviewer thing since it will show navigation buttons (back/forward) zoom and it also has a weird column behavior.

I want it in a simple [FlowDocumentScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.aspx) (or anything else that just displays the text without additional fuzz).

**EDIT:**
It's not only hyperlinks that is the problem. *Any* control, like Button, ListBox, ComboBox - anything that the user can interact with - is "grayed out" regardless of the IsEnabled properties if the FlowDocument is inside a FlowDocumentScrollViewer.

**EDIT2:**
Alright, it must have been a mistake or something from my end, because I ended up rewriting the control and now it works. I guess there was some sort if IsEnabled=False somewhere in the visual tree that caused this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a FlowDocumentScrollViewer for my about box:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <!-- ... -->
```

I don't have any of the controls or issues you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering whether you expecing some thing like this?

```
<TextBlock>
<Hyperlink>
    <Run Text="Test link"/>
</Hyperlink >
```

```
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I'd rather use FlowDocument since it gives me some additional formatting capabilities. (I'm using this for some simple online help for my app - just a dialog that briefly explains how to do a task)